# French school ebooks to download

Tags: ressources, apprentissage

Je suis un étudiant de français langue étrangère, et j'utilise une nouvelle méthode pour apprendre cette langue.  Avec cette nouvelle méthode, j'apprends à lire en premier, donc écouter, puis écrire, et ensuite, parler. Cependant, je veux apprendre avec plaisir, et je veux lire des livres qui m'intéressent. Par exemple, je veux lire de la physique dans un français facile et sans que ce soit trop technique. Je pense que les livres scolaires sont bien pour ça. Cependant, je n'arrive pas à trouver de site web pour télécharger des livres scolaires.

Il y a un site web pour langue grecque, où vous pouvez télécharger des livres scolaires. Par exemple, regardez à cette adresse:

[Le livre de la lumière pour première classe d'école primaire](http://www.pi-schools.gr/download/lessons/physics/dhmotiko/physics-e-dimotiko/fws.zip)

Où est-ce que je peux trouver ça en français ?

---

I'm a French language learner, and I use a new method to learn this language. In this new method, I first learn reading, then listening, then writing, and after that, speaking. However, I recently wanted to make my reading more fun, by reading simple texts about different fields of interest. For example, I'd like to read about physics, but in simple French, not in hard-to-read technical books. I thought of books of schools, and I think they are easy enough to be useful. However, I can't find any website to download French school ebooks.

There is a website for Greek language where you can download ebooks of school grades. You might for example take a look at this book:

[Book of light for first grade of primary school in Greece](http://www.pi-schools.gr/download/lessons/physics/dhmotiko/physics-e-dimotiko/fws.zip)

Where can I find free ebooks similar to this one, in French language?

Answer (score 8):

Tu auras du mal à trouver des manuels scolaires directement téléchargeables à cause des problèmes de copyright. 
Mais tu pourras peut-être trouver quelque chose qui t'intéresse à partir du portail FLE (Français Langue Étrangère) [Le Point du FLE](http://www.lepointdufle.net/).

Dans la rubrique *activités* il y a de nombreuses adresses probablement intéressantes. J'ai repéré ces deux là :

- [Cyberbouquins de FLE](http://www.fabgerard.com/cyberbouquin.html)
- [Écoute](http://www.ecoute.de/) qui est un site payant mais certains des articles sont toutefois accessibles gratuitement. En cherchant bien tu devrais trouver d'autres choses sur [Le Point du FLE](http://www.lepointdufle.net/).

**Edit** : il y a aussi le magazine en ligne [zigzag](http://www.zigzag-francophonie.eu) (qui se définit comme une « fenêtre ouverte sur la francophonie »), articles classés par thèmes.

---

It will be difficult to find French textbooks that are freely downloadable because of copyright issues. But you might find things of interest on the website [Le Point du FLE](http://www.lepointdufle.net/)  which is a very comprehensive portal of resources for French as a foreign language.

I've spotted those two :

- [Cyberbouquins de FLE](http://www.fabgerard.com/cyberbouquin.html)
- [Écoute](http://www.ecoute.de/) with some free resources (otherwise it's paying). If you have a thorough look at *activités* on [Le Point du FLE](http://www.lepointdufle.net/) you will probably find a lot more.

**Edit** : you can have a look at the online magazine [zigzag](http://www.zigzag-francophonie.eu) as well (self-advertized as “an open window on the French language”), including a thematic classification.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in mathematics, you can try the textbooks from Sésamath which are libre and free, ranging from CM2 (for ~10 year olds) to 3e (for ~14 year olds).

Comment: c'est tres utile. merci pour m'introduire ca ;).