# Learning the French language online

Tags: ressources, apprentissage

I am interested in learning French but don't know the first thing about it. I just love how it sounds as well as the complexity of it so I decided that I want to learn it.
What would be either the easiest or the fastest way to learn this language without getting a real life tutor? e.g. online lectures etc.

Comment: Welcome to fr.se! This question has been covered already here, please have a look at: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/492/1129 , http://french.stackexchange.com/q/2050/1129 , and basically anything under the [ressources tag](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ressources).